# Get Date objects back from min(dates):max(dates) in R?

Tags: r, date

Some R code:

```
> dates <- as.Date(c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'))
> min(dates)
[1] "2020-01-01"
> max(dates)
[1] "2020-01-02"

> min(dates):max(dates)
[1] 18262 18263
> as.Date(min(dates):max(dates))
Error in as.Date.numeric(min(dates):max(dates)) : 
  'origin' must be supplied
> as.Date(min(dates):max(dates), origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02"
```

This shows that `min` and `max` are working as expected, but when I put them in a range, the dates turn into integers.  How do I prevent that?

I can just use the "origin", but it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `:` and then reconverting the coerced numeric storage to `Date` class, use the `seq` which already have a method for `Date` class

```
seq(min(some_dates), max(some_dates), by = "1 day")
[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02"
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, but .. do you know why the range with ":" converts to numeric?

Comment: @dfrankow if you check `?":"`, -`Non-numeric arguments are coerced internally (hence without dispatching methods) to numeric`, though it says `from:to is equivalent to seq(from, to), and generates a sequence from from to to in steps of 1 or -1.` it would not dispatch the correct 'Date' method